# Compile from Windows 10 VS2017 Deploy on Windows 7 and ... DLL not found

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, windows-7

2.5 days that I try to the root of an error like

```
Could not load file or assembly "mydll.dll" or one of its dependencies.
The specified module could not be found
```

The project is a Windows C# based application. That dll is made in a C++ library inside the project. I am compile under Windows 10 64 bit with VS2017 Entreprise and have problem to deploy under Windows 7 64 bit (deployement under Windwos 10 works well...). All the .NET libs/exes/plugins target .NET 4.5.2 (which is installed on the deployement computer). The library use

```
Windows SDK Version: 8.1
Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2017 (v141)
```

The project make an msi installer, which I install successfully on the deployment computer. Of course the dll is there.

So I watched the execution of the programm with process monitor. The dll seem to be loaded several time.
The last time I see the following.

```
"10:31:13.7703319 AM","App.exe","1412","CloseFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor\Programm\ucrtbased.dll","SUCCESS",""
"10:31:13.7703575 AM","App.exe","1412","ReadFile","C:\Progra mFiles (x86)\Vendor\Programm\ucrtbased.dll","SUCCESS","Offset: 1,452,544, Length: 5,120, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal"
"10:31:13.7721639 AM","App.exe","1412","CreateFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor\Programm\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
"10:31:13.7722398 AM","App.exe","1412","CreateFile","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
"10:31:13.7723496 AM","App.exe","1412","CreateFile","C:\Windows\system\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
"10:31:13.7724133 AM","App.exe","1412","CreateFile","C:\Windows\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
"10:31:13.7725133 AM","App.exe","1412","CreateFile","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
"10:31:13.7725731 AM","App.exe","1412","CreateFile","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
"10:31:13.7726340 AM","App.exe","1412","CreateFile","C:\Windows\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
"10:31:13.7726991 AM","App.exe","1412","CreateFile","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
"10:31:13.7727622 AM","App.exe","1412","CreateFile","C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
"10:31:13.7729093 AM","App.exe","1412","CloseFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor\Programm\mydll.dll","SUCCESS",""
```

That *api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll* is indeed listed by dependency walker together with

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TIMEZONE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-ADVAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-OLE32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
GPSVC.DLL
MSISO.DLL
```

Google told me that all of this are irrelevant for this problem...
That is now 2.5 days to do what you do in 2.5 minutes under linux with `nm-D` and `ldd`...

Comment: `ucrtbased.dll` is a debug DLL, so you must be trying to deploy a debug version of your program and/or DLL.  The debug libraries are not available without installing the development environment and cannot be redistributed.  Make a release build and try again.  Once you have a release build, if it still does not work you will need to install the runtime redist package available with VS2017.

Comment: The probleme with negative downvote in SO is that they should at least tell why they downvote. The remark of Richard Critten (if anyhow related to the downvote) is not the cause of the issue, as making a Release version does not at all change the problem. After three days trying to target Win7 from Windows 10 I com to the conclusion that Microsoft developers have not foreseen this use case. It turns out you will indeed hit the Problem described there https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/06/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing/ (among others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 3 days trying to target efficiently Windows 7 from Windows 10, I share my experience and, I come to the following answer:
**This has never been foresseen by Microsoft developpers**. Some hack have been provided by MS but a reliable development chain can not be achieved.

1. Among other problems that you will hit, look at this [link](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/06/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing/) ..(Seriously you have to manually uninstall a Microsoft package in order to do a Microsoft Update? Seriously Microsoft?)
2. As of 2018 there is no efficient tool that can tell you what dynamic library is a missing in the Microsoft world (there is basically no equivalent of ldd)... don't even start to tell me about DependecyWalker or anything, it gives way too much false positive (>>100% signal to noise ratio) and is obsolete.

This together with the 1000 other Microsoft typical problems (Package conflicts etc..) that are not worth mentioning here, lead to say that doing this *may* be possible in theory but **is not** in practice. (I will not consider it practically feasible if it take hours or days for things that you would do in minutes under Linux)

My advice for readers is that if you need to target Win7, then make yourself a Win7 development virtual machine.

Of course problems arise if your company can only get-you a VS2017 and not a 2015. This dilema is exaclty known to Microsoft, it is in fact exactly their goal. Force you to buy a new product, or you customer to switch to a new OS...

Richard Critten's answer BTW was not related to this problem

Comment: `don't even start to tell me about DependecyWalker` - Did you check out the "new" [DependencyWalker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)? :)